# Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $A$, $B$ two non-empty subsets such that $A \cap \bar{B}=\{a\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $A$, $B$ two non-empty subsets such that $A \cap \bar{B}=\{a\}$ which means that $a \in A$ and the intersection of any neighbourhood of $a$ with $B$ is non-empty.

Under the assumption above, does not that mean the intersection of any neighbourhood of $A$ with $B$ would contain from $A$ at most the point $a$ and the rest is from $B$?

Comment: An example of this is the real numbers with the standard topology and the sets $A=(0,1], B=(1,2)$. Does this help?

Comment: @NicoTripeny you mean what I claimed is true?

Comment: Yes. It will look something like the example, except sets don’t generally have “end points”. This will just be from the definition of intersection more or less, nothing topological in nature.

Comment: @NicoTripeny thank you so much